# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/

Tags: vue.js, webpack

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
function generateHtmlPlugins(templateDir) {
  const templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, templateDir));
  return templateFiles.map(item => {
    const parts = item.split(".");
    const name = parts[0];
    const extension = parts[1];
    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename:${name}.html,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname,${templateDir}/${name}.${extension}),
      inject: false
    });
  });
}
const htmlPlugins = generateHtmlPlugins("./src/html/views");
const config = {
  entry: ["./src/main.js"],
  output: {
    filename: "./src/main.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  mode: "development",
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        extractComments: true
      })
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {}
          },
          {
            loader: "vue-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              url: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "vue-loader",
            options: {
              ident: "postcss",
              sourceMap: true,
              plugins: () => [
                require("cssnano")({
                  preset: [
                    "default",
                    {
                      discardComments: {
                        removeAll: true
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                })
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "vue-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/html/includes"),
        use: ["vue-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "./css/style.bundle.css"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "./src/fonts",
        to: "./fonts"
      },
      {
        from: "./src/favicon",
        to: "./favicon"
      },
      {
        from: "./src/img",
        to: "./img"
      },
      {
        from: "./src/uploads",
        to: "./uploads"
      }
    ])
  ].concat(htmlPlugins)
};
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === "production") {
    config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin());
  }
  return config;
};
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookie';
import vueHeadful from 'vue-headful';
import vueFooter from './components/template/Site-bottom'
import vueHeader from './components/template/Site-top'
import vueModalButton from './components/modal/button'
import vueCarouselItem from './components/modal/caruselItem'
import Tabs from 'vue-tabs-with-active-line';
import Vuelidate from './vuelidate'
import VueTelInput from 'vue-tel-input'
import VueTheMask from '../node_modules/vue-the-mask/dist/'
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.component('vue-headful', vueHeadful);
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueCookies);
Vue.use(Vuelidate);
Vue.use(VueTelInput);
Vue.use(VueTheMask);
Vue.component('vue-footer', vueFooter);
Vue.component('vue-header', vueHeader);
Vue.component('vue-modal-button', vueModalButton);
Vue.component('vue-carousel-item', vueCarouselItem);
Vue.component('Tabs', Tabs);
  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },enter code here
  template: '<App/>'
});
```

---

Вот такие ошибки выходят, нужно настроить правильно файл, а я не знаю как
[image: error]

Comment: установите модуль `vue-tabs-with-active-line`

Comment: по сути я пути прописал полные вместе с названием файла и ошибка исчезла выглядит так: ./node_modules/папка_модуля/скрипт.js

Comment: появилась после этого такая ошибка

Comment: ERROR in ./src/components/modal/caruselItem.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div class="carousel-item__foto">
|         <div class="carousel-item__wrapper" ref="carouselWrapper">
 @ ./src/main.js 10:0-69 29:35-50
 @ multi ./src/main.js